# Pandas how to convert a timestamp column (EST) to local TimeZone info available in other column

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp-with-timezone

From

```
colA (EST)                 colB (local tz) 
2016-09-19 01:29:13        US/Central
2016-09-19 02:16:04        Etc/GMT+2
2016-09-19 01:57:54        Europe/London
```

To

```
colA (EST)                 colB (local tz)      colC (timestamp in local tz)    
2016-09-19 01:29:13        US/Central           2016-09-19 02:29:13 
2016-09-19 02:16:04        Etc/GMT+2            2016-09-19 08:16:04
2016-09-19 01:57:54        Europe/London        2016-09-19 05:57:54
```

Comment: Shouldn't eastern 2016-09-19 01:29:13 to central be 2016-09-19 00:29:13-05:00?

Comment: Yup, you are correct. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the datetime column as timestamp and localize to US/Eastern time and then apply tz_convert

```
df['colA (EST)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colA (EST)']).dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
df['colC (timestamp in local tz) '] = df.apply(lambda x: x['colA (EST)']\
.tz_convert(x['colB (local tz)']), axis = 1)



    colA (EST)                 colB (local tz)  colC (timestamp in local tz)
0   2016-09-19 01:29:13-04:00   US/Central      2016-09-19 00:29:13-05:00
1   2016-09-19 02:16:04-04:00   Etc/GMT+2       2016-09-19 04:16:04-02:00
2   2016-09-19 01:57:54-04:00   Europe/London   2016-09-19 06:57:54+01:00
```

Comment: TypeError: ('Cannot convert tz-naive Timestamp, use tz_localize to localize', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: I assumed the date column is timezone aware, see the edit

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Do you know how to remove the timezone info from localized timestamp? Ex: Change timezone from '2016-09-19 00:29:13-05:00' to'2016-09-19 00:29:13'

Comment: Someone helped. This is the solution : df['ColB (New datetime)'] = df['ColA (Localized datetime)'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=None))