# Python - How to strip off timezone info from datetime object

Tags: python, timezone, timestamp

How to get ColB from ColA

```
ColA (Localized datetime)           ColB (New datetime)
2016-09-19 00:29:13-05:00           2016-09-19 00:29:13
2016-09-19 04:16:04-02:00           2016-09-19 04:16:04
2016-09-19 06:57:54+01:00           2016-09-19 06:57:54
```

Comment: checkout strftime/strptime function which allow to convert in given format.

Comment: What is the dtype of column `ColA (Localized datetime)`?

Comment: What do you see when you do df.dtypes?

Comment: dtype is object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas string slicing [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) on column as (Since Datatype is `object` as per OP):

```
df['ColB (New datetime)'] = df['ColA (Localized datetime)'].str[:-6]
```

Or:

```
df['ColB (New datetime)'] = df['ColA (Localized datetime)'].str.slice(start=0,stop=19)
```

---

```
print(df)

   ColA (Localized datetime)  ColB (New datetime)
0  2016-09-19 00:29:13-05:00  2016-09-19 00:29:13
1  2016-09-19 04:16:04-02:00  2016-09-19 04:16:04
2  2016-09-19 06:57:54+01:00  2016-09-19 06:57:54
```

**EDIT :**
Since the previous [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546515/8320861) output is `Timestamp` with inconsistent format across the column, Though the data type is `object` but each value is `Timestamp`:

```
df['ColB (New datetime)'] = df['ColA (Localized datetime)'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=None))
```

Comment: Its returns null value NaN

Comment: @vinotkr what is the datatype `df.dtypes` of the dataframe?. It is working fine if it is `object` datatype.

Comment: hmm..interesting. Basically, the datetime is a result from question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546068/

Comment: df['ColB (New datetime)'] = df['ColA (Localized datetime)'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=None)) works. Thanks everyone for your time :)

Comment: @vinotkr You are Welcome!. Please upvote and accept if the solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = ('2016-09-19 00:29:13-05:00,'
        '2016-09-19 04:16:04-02:00,'
'2016-09-19 06:57:54+01:00').split(',')

pd.DataFrame(data).astype(np.datetime64)
```

Comment: returns datetime in UTC

Comment: Yes, you can set to any timezone you desire.